# why the type casting not working in case of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, output

```
int i=5;

float*j;

j=(float*)&i;//type casting

printf("%f",*j);
```

The above code is printing `0.00000`.

Why it is not printing `5.00000` as I have type casted by `(float*)&i`;

Comment: Because casting is not magic; in this case it's just undefined behavior. `*(float *)&i` **reinterprets** the bytes of `i`. No actual conversion from `int` to `float` happens. It's the same raw memory, and you are just fooling the compiler. In contrast, if you had written `float j = i;` instead, then the assignment would have generated actual conversion code that would have made a proper `float` out of your `int` -- which, in memory, has a completely different representation.

Comment: How many legs does a sheep have if you call the tail a leg?  Still four. Calling a tail a leg does not make it a leg.

Answer (score 1):

The cast here is simply saying

> Take this pointer to an `int` and pretend it`s pointing to a`float`

In no way does this affect the underlying storage of the value (in this case `i`).  It has the exact set of bytes that it did before the pointer to the storage was converted.  As a result the language is now interpreting a float which happens to have the byte layout of an `int` with the value `5`.  Floating point numbers have a very specific memory layout as described here

> http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

In this particular case the value is being interpreted as a `0` floating point value

Comment: so why this casting works   `int (*p)[2],*pint;   p=&arr[0];  pint=(int*)p;`

Comment: @learner instead of emailing me please post it in a gist somewhere and link to it.  If you email it to me then other people trying to follow the conversation will be unable to do so because they can't see the full sample

Answer (score 0):

Pointer have to point to something: `&i` is the address of an integer in memory. Your cast says "pretend this pointer to an integer is really a pointer to a float, and then assign that pointer to j. You can *pretend* that, but it's still the address of i, which is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{

int s[4][2]={
            {10,20},
            {30,40},
            {50,60},
            {70,80},
          };
int (*p)[2],i,j,*pint;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    p=&s[i];
    pint=(int*)p;//conversion working fine
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(pint+j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is different - you are converting a pointer to an array of ints into a pointer to the first element of an array of ints. This works because both pointers are pointing to the same kind of thing in memory. The problem with your original example was trying to pretend a pointer to a float was the same as a pointer to an int - it's not, because floats and ints are stored differently.